# calling jquery facbox from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

i am using [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)

that give help for opening box from link

but i want to open box from jquery click function not from hyper link.

like
            $("#Button2").click(function() 
             {
             code to open facebox
             });

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

```
$("#Button2").click(function() { 

  // to load html/php page
  jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' });
  jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.php' });

  // load image
  jQuery.facebox({ image: 'images/dude.jpg' });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

something like: jQuery.facebox('hi there')

Comment: yes work for me. can we call other html or php file into it.?